# Restify 2.6 post data

Tags: node.js, curl, restify

I just start to try Restify (and NodeJS in general) and I have some trouble to get the users POST data.

I have a basic Node app. On the documentation and some blog posts I read it's as simple as using the queryParser but it's not working. I think the problem is on my CURL command.

Node App:

```
var restify = require('restify');

function userCreation(request, result, next) {
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log(request.query);
  console.log(request.params);
  result.send({ name: request.params.name });
  return next();
}

var server = restify.createServer({ version: '1.0.0' });
server.use(restify.gzipResponse());
server.use(restify.queryParser());

server.post({ path: '/users', versions: ['1.0.0'] }, userCreation);

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

CURL command:

```
curl -is -X POST -H 'accept-version: 1.0.0' -d '{ "name": "John" }' http://127.0.0.1:8080/users

curl -is -X POST -H 'accept-version: 1.0.0' -d 'name=John' http://127.0.0.1:8080/users
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 09:40:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{}
```

And the Node logs are:

```
restify listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080
undefined
{}
{}
```

Hope somebody can help me :)

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Use `bodyParser` instead of of `queryParser`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to process JSON documents sent via HTTP POST requests in your RESTful service you will need :

1. Use ***bodyParser*** in your service
2. Make sure to ***include the HTTP Header "Content-Type: application/json"*** when you submit the HTTP POST request

Your CURL command should be something like:

> curl -is -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H
>   "accept-version: 1.0.0" -d '{ "name": "John" }'
>   http://127.0.0.1:8080/users

Your Restify Service code:

```js
var restify = require('restify');

function userCreation(request, result, next) {
  console.log(request.body);
  result.send({
    name: request.body.name
  });
  return next();
}

var server = restify.createServer({
  version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(restify.gzipResponse());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.post({
  path: '/users',
  versions: ['1.0.0']
}, userCreation);

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Good Luck!